# Apache - .htaccess regex substitution in RewriteCond

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To replace `localhost:8888/dev/test.php` to `localhost:8888/dev/test/`, this was the .htaccess I created

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/test/ /$1/test.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dev/test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/test.php$ /$1/test/ [L,R=301]
```

I tried to substitute `/dev/` in `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dev/test\.php [NC]` with `/$1/` to get the value from the rewriteRule but this doesn't seem to work as the URL remains as `http://localhost:8888/dev/test.php` instead of `localhost:8888/dev/test/`

> What should be the format of the regex needed to substitute `/dev/` in RewriteCond?

Comment: What actually happens? An error? Nothing? Is the request correctly routed when you request `/dev/test/`?

Comment: @w3dk url remains as `localhost:8888/dev/test.php`

Comment: But what about `/dev/test/`? Is this correctly routed? (Which is what the first directive is processing.)

Comment: @w3dk yes, that works fine, the code I provide generates the URL. Only the substitution causes the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/test/ /$1/test.php [NC,L]
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dev/test\.php [NC]
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/test.php$ /$1/test/ [L,R=301]
> ```

These rules should be reversed. The external redirect should be *before* the *internal rewrite*. Otherwise, when the rewriting process starts over, it is rewritten back to `/dev/test.php` (the first directive).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dev/test\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/test\.php$ /$1/test/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/test/ /$1/test.php [NC,L]
```

In per-directory `.htaccess` files the `/?` at the start of the pattern is not necessary.

The check against `THE_REQUEST` is simply to avoid a redirect loop. Instead, you can check the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is empty on the initial request:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/test\.php$ /$1/test/ [L,R=301]
```

**UPDATE:**

> I want to substitute `^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dev/test\.php` with something like `^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /$1/test\.php`

Since you are using a catch-all wildcard in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, this sort of thing does not seem to be necessary? Just make it a catch-all wildcard in the *CondPattern*? For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*/test\.php\ HTTP [NC]
```

I'd also question whether the `NC` was necessary here? Do you specifically need to allow `TEST.PHP`, etc.?

Comment: That is not what I was asking, I want to substitute `^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dev/test\.php` with something like `^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /$1/test\.php `.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to do that? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh, I got confused with rewrite rule, thought that needed substitution too, which is indeed pointless... Haha Thanks, this is how it is supposed to be. But Request_Status doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `REDIRECT_STATUS`.